# multiples sitios Django Apache

Tags: django, apache

tengo una aplicación en producción con Apache Mod WSGI la cual funciona bien la configuración la tengo algo asi(**django.conf**):

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        WSGIDaemonProcess rgmanagement python-path=/var/www/html/inventariosRG:/home/roo/vproduccion/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIScriptAlias /rgmanagement /var/www/html/inventariosRG/inventarios/wsgi.py process-group=rgmanagement
        WSGIDaemonProcess facturacion python-path=/var/www/html/facturacion:/home/roo/vproduccion/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIScriptAlias /facturacion /var/www/html/facturacion/inventarios/wsgi.py process-group=facturacion
        <Directory /var/wwww/html/inventariosRG/inventarios>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/html/inventariosRG/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/inventariosRG/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/facturacion/inventarios>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/html/facturacion/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/facturacion/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/html/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

dicha configuración funciona perfecto para una **APP**

Ahora el problema tengo un proyecto X el cual funcional bien, tengo otro proyecto Y el cual es lo mismo que X pero con ligeros cambios en los archivos estaticos(javascript) al poner en producción el proyecto X y Y este ultimo toma la ruta de static incorrecta es decir de X cuando deberia coger el de Y.

Gracias por sus comentarios uso CentOS 7

Comment: Diego, cuál es el inconveniente que estás teniendo? Hasta ahora lo único que dices es que todo funciona bien, no encuentro el error, voto para que sea cerrada por no estar claro qué se pregunta

Comment: Perdon el error es que al acceder a una app, no coge los cambios actuales en produccion, pero si ejecuto "manage.py runserver" si se ve los cambios y al parecer es el problema con la puesta en produccion..

Comment: Lo que sucede es que cada vez que haces un cambio en producción, si estás trabajando con una solución ya sea apache, nginx, o cualquiera, debes reiniciar el servidor, normalmente con `sudo service apache restart` de esta forma el servidor toma los nuevos cambios, ya que todo tu código se carga en memoria. Lo que hace `runserver` es crear un servicio que cada vez que escucha un cambio en tus archivos reinicia toda la configuración, de esta forma siempre tienes el código actualizado

Comment: @GermanAlzate volvi a editar mi pregunta ..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos alias definidos con el mismo nombre, por lo que te coge el primer alias indicado, es decir, los estáticos de `inventariosRG`.

Si tienes 2 apps, la forma de trabajar es tener una carpeta de estáticos por cada app, posteriormente ejecutas `manage.py collectstatic` y se recopilarán todos los estáticos de todas las apps a la carpeta indicada en la variable `STATIC_ROOT` de tu `settings.py`.

En apache solo tienes que indicar un único alias para `static`, la ruta del `STATIC_ROOT`, que es dónde vas a tener todos los recursos.

Answer (score 0):

yo definiría varios vhost diferentes ya con sus dominios y sus enviroments separados, en mi caso tengo varios servidores con varios sitios en django funcionando 
aqui el sitio1.vhost

```
<Directory /var/www/sitio1.com>
    AllowOverride None
            Require all denied
    </Directory>

    WSGIPythonPath /var/www/sitio1.com/web/:/var/virtualenv/sitio1.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/sitio1.com/web
    RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                                   

    ServerName sitio1.com
    ServerAlias www.sitio1.com www.sitio1.com.ar sitio1.com.ar


    Alias /error/ "/var/www/sitio1.com/web/error/"
```

...
...

y asi los siguientes proyectos